# Can anybody recommend an app in google drive for editing c++ files?

Tags: c++, text-editor, google-drive-api

I store my school programming work on google drive. From home I just access the google drive file on my computer, but I can't do that from school.

Can anybody recommend an app for editing cpp files in google drive? Preferably free, poor college student and all that.

I found drivecode, but it doesn't seem to work with cpp files and on header files it's not doing any markup.

Neutron Drive seems like exactly what I need, but it's not free.

Alternatively, any suggestions on another cloud-based development platform that I could use would work too.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but couldn't you just download the file(s) from drive and upload them when you're done working with them?

Comment: I can, I'm trying to avoid that if I can. It's just a convenience thing, and hopefully if I'm not moving files around I won't accidentally overwrite the wrong thing, or make duplicates, or ... well, any number of user errors that my scatterbrained self is likely to make. That was actually what I did last semester.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure you knew about that option.

Comment: I agree with Joe, it'll just require some discipline when you've updated s.th. at home you need to synchronize it at school. Or is it the problem you don't have access to your [tag:google-drive] account from school?

Comment: I can access the account. It really is just a convenience issue; if I can access it through google drive without having to download/upload, then I'm less likely to make a mistake and wind up losing work or having duplicate files and having to figure out which one is recent, etc. I can't install the drives at school to actually synch it, so I have to make a temp solution and import the files to do the editing then re-upload, and as my projects get larger, that will get more tedious.

Comment: @DanielBall You could also consider to have a free [GitHub](https://github.com/) repo instead of [tag:google-drive] for your projects. So you could have control about your concerns about synchronizing your code.

Comment: You know that cloud serves as additional storage facility and mainly as free software provider (here an editor) but you should have and edit your files locally if you can. And consider GitHub as g-makulik suggests.

Comment: Also not quite an answer, but how about using mercurial, git, bazaar or svn to store your files on a remote server, and then use the version control software to copy files - back and forth - with the added advantage of having "Oops, I changed something I didn't want to change" backtracking as well.

Comment: @SChepurin I keep a local backup as well, yes. Several years as a sysadmin taught me that nothing is safe ;)

Comment: @ Daniel Ball - Ah! This must be a very high school programming ) But seriously, consider what Mats and g-makulik suggest.

Comment: It does look like github is probably the way to go ... even if I found an editor in google drive, I think the version control would be more helpful to me. Thanks everybody for your suggestions!

Comment: If you are talking about convenience, having a local file and a *good* ide/environment is probably much more convenient for programming than having a distributed file and a crappy editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

screw Google driver, for single files use

https://gist.github.com/
http://collabedit.com/

for large project as said above, start learning mercurial. later you will need it professionally.

Answer (score -1):

In light of the comments under the question, I think the best option is actually to use a service like [gitHub](https://github.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/about/), [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/), or [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/), because of the availability of version control in those platforms.

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to try out Google Code, it's not quite as advanced as GIT and hopefully it's not blocked either.  Also, you already have a Google account, so you won't have to make a new account for anything.

Google Code allows full editing capabilities online, but you can also create a repository using it and download your code when you're ready to compile.  You may need to learn a little bit about it before you can start, but once you upload your code you can edit it all right there, and it also formats automatically, making it better than Drive.

If Google Code is in fact blocked, I would also suggest trying GIT or some other service, but they're a little more advanced.  Google Code has served me well for simple projects in the past.

Go to http://code.google.com